# Solving $a_1x^{4999} + a_2x^{4998} + a_3x^{4997}+...+a_{5000}x^{0}=n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

How can we solve the equation

$$a_1x^{4999} + a_2x^{4998} + a_3x^{4997}+...+a_{5000}x^{0}=n$$

if we know the values $a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_{5000},n$? Are there any open source solutions?

Comment: Tag description: **DO NOT USE THIS TAG.** The algebra tag is no longer being used. Please use the [algebra-precalculus] tag or the [abstract-algebra] tag instead.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you get this problem?  I assume you want a numerical solution, but it seems difficult to even evaluate this polynomial numerically.

Comment: of course it is from not-so-friendly geometric-like sequence and I solved it using WolframAlpha trial and verified it myself using binary search. And it turns out that solving the equation this way was wrong for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Abel–Ruffini theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) tells us you can not solve (exactly) for the roots of this polynomial, since it is of degree $>4$

Comment: This is true for the generic polynomial, but can be very wrong for specific polynomials. For instance, we know the exact roots of $1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n=0$ for every $n$.

Comment: @AndreaMori ofcourse the Galois group of the polynomial can be solvable, but the OP was looking for an open sorce code and such a thing should give a correct outpit for every input. Numerical methods are the only real options, unless the case is very trivial.

Comment: Absolutely. I guess that I was suggesting that although the situation looks bad in general, sometimes we do get lucky.